# How to manage microservices?

Tags: architecture, project-management, microservices

We are trying to adopt the microservice approach to our newly developed application.

However, we found that there are too many repos, branches, and releases need to be managed. Originally, we only have 2~4 repos to manage for an application. After adopting the microservice approach, we may have 10~20 repos for an application with the same complexity.

So, are there any best practices on how to manage these microservices of a large application?

Comment: Well, this raises a lot of questions. What is your application? Why did you decide to switch to microservices? Why did you decide to create more repos? (microservices don't *require* more repos) Are these all controlled by one team, or shared by many? Why is 10~20 repos difficult to manage? Do you have continuous integration/deployment?

Answer (score 5):

### Standardization, Automation and Virtualization.

Initially with the first few microservices it's not too bad.  Different developers have their machines configured differently which presents some challenges but usually these can be quickly addressed.  But once you get past 3 or 4 services things get tricky.  Small differences in environments become a constant pain.  Making sure everyone has the same environment without much work and managing the flow of code becomes very burdensome as you are seeing / have found.

The approaches I have seen to help address this are:

#### Standardization

Define the set of services.  Define how they run.  Define what ports things run on.  Define some standards and make sure they are followed.  Use virtualization (below) to implement these standards universally without effort.

#### Automation

You want 1-step (or as few steps as possible) to create and update environment procedures.  There may be 100 *actual* steps but you want to reduce that to as few as possible so that updating your environment with the constant flow of changes is very easy.  You want to avoid even needing procedures and following detailed steps.  You should be able to update and get things running in less than 5 minutes and ideally less than 1 minute.

#### Virtualization

With this, for example Vagrant, you can make sure that, unlike the local individual developers environment (which may be highly customzied) virtual machines (for development) give the opportunity to have EXACTLY the same environment, same settings, profiles, dot files, etc. separate from developers personal environments.

---

Using the above will not necessarily reduce the amount of repos, branches, releases.  However it will help make it easy to do and not burdensome.  One thing that I am seeing with the organizations I have seen take on this challenge is that this is a new area that takes time and effort to get right.  You may need to dedicate specific resources to get it right and keep it maintained.

For actual releases you will need to put more effort into defining how things work so that the pattern can be repeated.  You will need to spend more time and effort to get this right when compared to a 1 repo release setup.  The idea generally though is that with smaller repos and smaller changes, if you have a repeatable deployment process, it will be easier to deploy individual pieces.  Automation of the processes is also key here.

Comment: I have no idea whether this addresses the OP's question, but it does address the most obvious replies to my "Why is 10~20 repos difficult to manage?" comment, so provisional +1.

Comment: Yeah, I agree it's a little off-focus and could be improved.  Doesn't really address the 'releases' part of the question.

Comment: So I've added a little more on deployment.